# postgres jdbc connection string with ssl certficate ( without keystore)

Tags: postgresql, jdbc

We want to connect the PostgreSQL db through jdbc using the self signed certificate. Keystore option is available but i want to pass the certificate though my jdbc command line . is there any option available for the same

Comment: You may use a self signed cert with Postgres and JDBC ([see here](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/91/ssl-client.html)), but keep in mind that importing the cert into Java is somewhat non trivial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html#ssl), the URL will look somewhat like this:

`jdbc:postgresql://host:port/database?ssl=true&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory&sslcert=/path/to/cert&sslkey=/path/to/key`

This assumes that the client doesn't need to verify the server's certificate, but the server will verify the client's certificate.

Answer (score 0):

the sslmode if set to require, will not verify the CA cert or hostname. it is best fit for self signed cert. No need keystore.
jdbc:postgresql://host:port/database?ssl=true&sslmode=require

If you want to verify the CA, can do it like:
jdbc:postgresql://host:port/database?ssl=true&sslmode=verify-full&sslrootcert=/my-path/hey.pem

Comment: Please use code blocks when providing an instruction/command to for the user to enter.